# how do I toggle between the 2 between plus and minus element?

Tags: jquery

I have two ids one id ="231-plus " and second id="231-minus". I want to be able to change the plus to minus when open. When closed i want to switch back the minus back to plus.

It does the toggle but its not cwitching back from minus to plus once opened and and then closed.

My code is here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/rtxmpq8h/15/)

Javascript

```
function toggle() {
    $("#showhide").click(function(){
        $("#lorem1").toggle(1000,function(){
            $("#231-minus").show();
             $("#231-plus").hide();
        });

         $("#lorem2").toggle();
         $("#lorem3").toggle();
    });    

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    toggle();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't written the `toggle` functionality for `lorem2` or `lorem3`. Also, you **always** show the minus and hide the plus, they should both toggle. Based on the HTML in your fiddle, your code would look like this:

```
$("#showhide").click(function(){
    $("#lorem1").toggle(1000,function(){
        $("#231-minus").toggle();
         $("#231-plus").toggle();
    });

    $("#lorem2").toggle(1000,function(){
        $("#500-minus").toggle();
         $("#500-plus").toggle();
    });
     $("#lorem3").toggle(1000,function(){
        $("#850-minus").toggle();
         $("#850-plus").toggle();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rtxmpq8h/18/)

Answer (score 0):

May I request something  different? There is a method called "toggle" contained in the ["classList"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

The basic syntax works like

```
element.classList.toggle("yourClass");
```

You are able to toggle this class on each of your element ("#123-minus" and "#123-plus").

```js
function onClick(){
  
  //get each DIV in the HTML section
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  
  //loop through the DIVs and either remove or add the class "hide"
  for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    divs[i].classList.toggle("hide");
  }
}
```

```css
.hide{
  display: none;
}

#minus{
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

#plus{
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="onClick()" id="minus" class="hide"></div>
<div onclick="onClick()" id="plus"></div>
```

Click on the divs to execute the toggle.